# Laravel passport api unsupported_grant_type error

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I install successfully passport api in laravel, I can get access_token 
 using requesting tokens like

```
   Route::get('/redirect', function () {
  $query = http_build_query([
      'client_id' => '1',
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
      'response_type' => 'code',
      'scope' => '',
  ]);

     return redirect('http://localhost:8000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
  });
```

but when I use password grant tokens, `created by php artisan passport:client --password`,  using username and password,
I get unsupported_grant_type

my request is,

```
   $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
       'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '3',
        'client_secret' => 'sqgaA8HOBUZBBZwWnl4xhyDE7LWyhAhlG5BZa199',
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'scope' => '',
        ],
      ]);

     return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

I get error like this;

```
 {
 "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
 "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
 "hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter"
  }
```

my oauth_clients table is,

```
  id      => 3
  user_id => 1
  name    => Laravel Password Grant Client
  secret  => sqgaA8HOBUZBBZwWnl4xhyDE7LWyhAhlG5BZa199
  redirect => http://localhost
  personal_access_client => 0
  password_client => 1
  revoked => 0
  created_at => 2019-03-27 15:46:10
  updated_at => 2019-03-27 15:46:10
```

Comment: It does not work when I use restlet crome extension to post data,

Comment: Your `client_id => '3'` should be `client_id => 3` . Try removing the quotes.

Comment: my post request is http://localhost:8000/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&grant_type=password&client_secret=sqgaA8HOBUZBBZwWnl4xhyDE7LWyhAhlG5BZa199&username=myusername&password=mypassword&scope=*   @Hari Harker

Comment: In your request your `redirect_uri` is `http://example.com/callback` but in the `oauth_clients` table it is `http://localhost`. Change it accordingly and have a route definition for your callback uri. Also, ensure the `APP_URL` is set to proper app uri (http:\\localhost or your domain root uri) in your `.env` file